# Foreground using data binding is not working in some devices

Tags: android, android-databinding

I use data binging in a view holder of a recycler view. For showing an inactive row, I set foreground to a color and this is working perfect on my Nexus6 and many other devices.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:foreground="@{subscribed.isAutoRenew() ? @color/transparent : @color/bg_inactive}">
        other stuff ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is this code is not working on Samsung SM-N900 with android 5.0. I can solve it by using java code instead of data binding. Any suggestion how to solve it by data binding?

Comment: Would you mind posting what java code you're using that works? Data binding will be using the equivalent of `view.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)))`. If your java code differs, try that java code out and see if it fails as well.

Comment: I used the same code as you mentioned and it's working. I should mention here that I wrapped the relative layout with a frame layout because setForground method of relative layout requires API level 23.

Answer (score 1):

Data binding avoids method calls that don't exist on older platforms. If the device that you're testing on is older than API 23 (Marshmallow), then it will refuse to call `setForeground()`. Data Binding doesn't have a magical way to give the RelativeLayout the foreground capability, so you'll have to do what you do in the Java Code. Give your layout a FrameLayout wrapper and assign the foreground to it.

```
<FrameLayout ... 
    android:foreground="@{subscribed.isAutoRenew() ? @color/transparent : @color/bg_inactive}">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">
    other stuff ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

-- edit --

Based on the comment, I must conclude that there must be a bug in Data Binding in which it detects the version of `View.setForeground()` and sees that it is API 23, so skips it. It must not be checking `FrameLayout.setForegound()`. I'll file a bug on this.

In the mean time, you can work around it by creating your own BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:foreground")
public static void setForeground(FrameLayout view, Drawable drawable) {
    view.setForeground(drawable);
}
```

Comment: As I commented above, I did test it, and it didn't work in that special device. So I had to implement it in java code.

Comment: Thanks for the BindingAdapter! Strangely I did not need it using Android Studio (3.0.1), but in Intellij (2017.2.5) it was necessary! Very same PC and identical code. Strange.